# Do I need to call delete to a pointer assigned to another pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have this:

```
char* data = new char[3];
char* tmp = data;
data = new char[3];
```

after that should I call delete for both pointers like so:

```
delete[] data;
delete[] tmp;
```

or is it just for data:

```
delete[] data;
```

I tried the first way but it gave me a heap error, the second way didn't cause me any problems, but then what happens to the memory tmp is pointing to, would there be a memory leak there?.

Comment: For every call to `new` (or `new []`), you need to have a corresponding call to `delete` (or `delete []`). You called `new []` twice, so you need to call `delete []` twice.

Comment: Ok but what gives me troubles is that if I call delete to data before reassigning it that would delete the values in the memory tmp is pointing to, so my question is if there's a way to free the memory in tmp.

Comment: The code, as you have written it (that is, the sequence of statements: `char* data = new char[3]; char* tmp = data; data = new char[3]; delete[] data; delete[] tmp;`) is perfectly fine, and will correctly free all the memory that was allocated. If you have problems in your code, it's because you're doing something different from what you posted.

Comment: The first is fine. You have not posted all of your code. Please post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I would say rather that you should simply not write code like this in the first place. It only causes confusion.

Comment: Ok I just rebuild my project and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand that the `delete` operator releases any memory that was allocated by a previous `new`. So depending upon, the occurrence of new, the call to delete for the same allocated memory should match.

In your case, there are two invocation to `new`, `new char[3]` assigned to `data` which was further assigned to `tmp`. At this point, both `tmp` and `data` refers (points) to the same memory location on the heap. A second invocation of `new` , `new char[3]` further allocates memory equivalent to 3 character storage and assigns it to `data`. Thus it would make sense, to call `delete` twice on both the allocated blocks, refereed individually by `tmp` and `data`.

Comment: So I call delete to tmp aswell

Comment: @Mr.Fahrenheit: Yes

Comment: The problem is it wont let me do that, it triggers a breakpoint, I guess is because I didn't use new with tmp.

Comment: It shows a message saying that my project triggered a breakpoint then it shows this function:

Comment: extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(void const* const block)
{
    if (!block)
        return FALSE;

    return HeapValidate(__acrt_heap, 0, header_from_block(block));
}

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. There is a heap corruption somewhere in your code. Use `valgrind` or something similar to know if there is a `double delete` or an `invalid write`